# React Material UI makeStyle issues

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, web-development-server

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toolbarMargin: {
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    marginBottom: "3em",
  },
  logo: {
    height: "7em",
  },
  tabContainer: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
  },
  tab: {
    ...theme.typography.toolbar,
    minWidth: 10,
    marginLeft: "25px",
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: "50px",
  },
}));

export default function Header(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <ElevationScroll>
        <AppBar position="fixed" color="primary">
          <Toolbar disableGutters>
            <img alt="company logo" src={logo} className={classes.logo} />
            <Tabs className={classes.tabContainer}>
              <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Home" />
              <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Services" />
              <Tab className={classes.tab} label="The Revolution" />
              <Tab className={classes.tab} label="About Us" />
              <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Contact Us" />
            </Tabs>
       
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />
    </>
  );
}
```

i am updating the css for tab for in localHost its not updating like its not working.

```
export default createTheme({
 
  typography: {
    tab: {
      fontFamily: "Raleway",
      textTransform: "none",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: "1rem",
    },
  },
});
```

this is theme.js file

i want to get tab css working . like i am changing the font and other property of tab label its not reflecting.
please help me out i will be very thankfull .

Answer (score 0):

> 

try this and revert me back if this works or not

Comment: what ?? nothing is showing